# OOD - passing data to model (MVC)

Tags: java, android, oop, parse-platform, loose-coupling

I want to pass a form to a model I made (MVC)
in terms of OOD principles and loose coupling, what attitude is preferred?

1) pass all the details of the new user from the form(username, password,phone,etc.) to the model to a single or overloaded method?
or:

2)pass a single object (say "User" or "ParseUser"(an object of parse cloud service - parse.com)) to the model.

the pros and cons:
If I pass the ParseUser object , tommorrow parse.com can change the object and  I will have to change the code from all the "clients"(=callers) instead of just changing them from the model.
whereas if I pass the details into an overloaded method (something like (signUpUser("Dave","abc234",+834-000-000-00)) I think it is also contradict the loose coupling principle because there is more data (multiple variables) to pass between entities , and it looks more messy...

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to go with the second approach

pass a single object (say "User" or "ParseUser"(an object of parse cloud service - parse.com)) to the model. Passing a single object with its properties saves you a lot of code. Anyway in future if the third party modifies it's object you have to anyway refactor your code in both the scenarios.

> If I pass the ParseUser object , tommorrow parse.com can change the
>   object and I will have to change the code from all the
>   "clients"(=callers) instead of just changing them from the model.

Say if ParseUser object is passing a property "time" to your application, you are adding that to your model & accessed by n clients. In future parse.com deprecates that property you would have to refactor you code in both the scenarios whether you add every property individually to the model or directly add a single object to the model. You have to change the code in your model.

Passing a single object is cleaner & reduces code.

You can write a [wrapper class](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/107338/using-third-party-libraries-always-use-a-wrapper) for accessing parse.com API this will provide abstraction for your application.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I think there is a little misunderstanding I have to clarify, and you have to consider it : If I pass it as a multiple variables and parse.com deprecate the time property, I DON'T need to change the code in all the n clients, because I can just change the method in the model that will ignore the time. whereas in the second approach I have to  change all the clients because there is no more such property ParseUser.time and trying to change it will cause error.

Comment: Say a client "A" in its class is using time provided by yourMethod() now if you change your method & stop sending time, won't it break the the client's code. As it is already expecting the time field from you? This scenario will be same whether you add individual fields to the model or a single object. You have to change your API & notify the client that the field has been deprecated. It's agnostic of how you add the property to the model. Also have a look at the builder pattern. It constructs the object based on the input parameters.

Comment: what you mention about wrapper and builders seems useful for my case,I'll read about that. however, I do want to explain why using method/overloaded method will NOT require any update at the client code. let's say the client first looked something like that:
<pre><code>
MyParseModel.createNewUser(username,password,age,time);
</pre></code>
and the Model code (server) is:
<pre><code>

public static void createNewUser(){<br/>
ParseUser pu = new ParseUser;
pu.username=username;
pu.password=password;
pu.age=age;
pu.time=time // you just have to delete this line!
}
</pre></code>

Comment: @Amitay you don't understand this, say you have this code in your API which you have provided in the above statement & I am using your API & using this property time in n places in my code. Now you have removed the time property from your new method. Won't I also have to remove the time property from all over my code? What will replace time? It will break my code.

Comment: I guess it is another story if I release an API, but right now I just use Parse's API and I'm talking about the changes THEY will make at the object ParseUser which is THEIR object. today there is an email property to ParseUser, may be tomorrow the will deprecate it, so even if the user will type his email, if I'll just delete the line ParseUser.email=email everything will be OK

Comment: My answer was as per your line " If I pass the ParseUser object , tommorrow parse.com can change the object and I will have to change the code from all the "clients"(=callers) instead of just changing them from the model." I assumed your application is serving further many clients. Anyways you've got the idea what I am trying to convey.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry for the misunderstanding . clients is also a name for modules/classes that request something from another classes ("servers"). Anyway  , I absolutely have a lot more idea about this issue from this conversation. So thanks.